# Algorithm for tile connection in a two-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, path-finding

I have a simple `Tile`-Class, which has the property `IsBlack`. I'm working with a **two-dimensional array** (`Tile[,]`).

I'd like to check whether all white fields (those where `IsBlack=false`) are connected. Following examples would return `true`:

[image]
[image]

Whereas following would return `false`:

[image]

I have a number of ideas, though I think they are rather inefficient:

- Run a path-finding algorithm from between every single tile (very inefficient)
- Find "rectangles" of black tiles. (For example, the first image has 1 rectangle, the "border") There must be only 1. (not sure if this approach is valid)

Comment: You want a situation where whole column is black means if any column has any white space it returns true

Comment: You may want to look at [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling) algorithm. It is very similar to the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Search in raster order for a white field
2. Run a [floodfill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) algorithm from that point and mark which tiles you have visited
3. Continue searching to see if there are any more white fields that are not marked as visited

If steps 3 finds an unvisited white, then return false, otherwise return true.

Answer (score 0):

1. Rapresent your structure as a graph: an edge between node A and B exist if the two have an edge in common in the tile rapresentation (assuming diagonal moves are not allowed)
2. Run DFS, and keep a record of the nodes you have touched.

If after running 2 some of the nodes are missing, the space is partitioned.